# Missing Operator or Semicolon after Self.Free

Tags: delphi

I am trying to make a simple login form. When the login is successful, `Form2` should be shown and `Form1` should be hiden or closed. But I get a compiler error *"Missing operator or semicolon"*.

Here is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if(Key.Text = 'password') then
    Form2.Show
    Self.close //Same error with Self.Free or Self.Release
  else
    ShowMessage('Failed');
    Exit;
end;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a `begin/end` block (and you don't need the `Exit`):

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (Key.Text = 'password') then
  begin // <-- add this
    Form2.Show;
    Self.Close;
  end // <-- add this
  else
    ShowMessage('Failed');
end;
```

Comment: Also missing two semicolons (after the `Show` and `Close`).

Comment: Thanks, but i need 1 more help get error in self.close when click button1 so i change it to form1.hide but how to close form1 when i close form2

Comment: You did not say what the error is. `Self.Close;` works just fine in general, however do note that by default, closing the `MainForm` will terminate the program. So, assuming `TForm1` is your `MainForm`, this kind of code is not particularly useful as it is currently shown.

Comment: yes Form1 is MainForm, so how to close it without terminate the program i just want close/hide Form1 but Form2 still show and when i close Form2, Form1 will closed too. sorry for my bad english

Comment: You cannot `Close` the `MainForm` without terminating the program. You will have to `Hide` it instead. Your button can call `Self.Hide` (which incidently will also hide your app's taskbar button if `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar` is true) and `Form2.Show`, and then Form2's `OnClose` event can call `Form1.Close`.

Comment: @KenWhite: Actually, the semicolon after "Close" (or to be more precise: Before "end") is unnecessary, as a semicolon in Pascal is a statement _seperator_ and not (like in C-style languages) a statement _terminator_.

Comment: @HeartWare: Yes, but not in the code posted, because it is followed by additional code other than `end;`.  Read the code posted in the OP. `if... then Something SomeOtherThing else` requires a semicolon after `Something`. I'm extremely familiar with the syntax. Thanks, though. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite: The code you posted doesn't need the semicolon after "Close", and it _mustn't_ have one after "end" (because it is followed by "else"). Try it yourself... Remove the semicolon after "Self.Close" and it will compile just fine...

Comment: @HeartWare: The code *I posted* doesn't have a `Close`. Are you missing something here? (I didn't post any code. The original poster of the question posted the code that had the missing semicolons, just as the compiler error stated.)

Comment: @KenWhite: Sorry - didn't notice that the code posted wasn't yours (I read your comment and overlooked that the code was posted by Remy). In any case, to solve the problem, the OP didn't need to put semicolons after the "Close" statement (after adding the begin/end), but only after the "Show" statement. Adding (only) the two semicolons wouldn't have helped either, as then the compiler would have complained about the "else" without an "if", so I interpreted your comment as to mean that a semicolon should be put after the two statements _as well as_ adding the begin/end of Remy's code.